# How to stack \Rightarrow and \nLeftarrow?

Tags: arrows, math-operators, logic

I would like specify an operator that combines "implies" and "is not implied by".  What I have in mind is something like a $\Rightarrow$ stacked over $\nLeftarrow$.  I tried all of the following, but the resulting typeset expressions all look wrong:

```
P \overset{\Rightarrow}{\nLeftarrow} Q              % \Rightarrow is too high
P \underset{\nLeftarrow}{\Rightarrow} Q             % \nLeftarrow is too low
P \overset{\Rightarrow}{\underset{\nLeftarrow}{}} Q % \Rightarrow is too high and \nLeftarrow is too low
```

Basically, in each of the above the vertical positioning of one or both of the arrow operators is off, as described more specifically in the comments.

What I want, instead, is a stack of both arrows where the top one is *slightly* above the midline and the bottom one is *slightly* below the midline.

Comment: Please note that since Mathjax has notthing to do with LaTeX and friends it is generally off topic here (even if there is a `mathjax` tag). We have no knowledge or control over how `mathjax` displays stuff.

Comment: @daleif: thanks for the pointer; I've removed all references to MathJax from my post; I'll just hope that the general answer will give me a clue on how to do it with MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly general method for obtaining two arrows on top of each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twoarrows}[3][0.2ex]{%
  % #1 = optional space correction, #2 = above, #3 = below
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\twoarrows@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\twoarrows@}[2]{\twoarrows@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\twoarrows@@}[4]{%
  % #1 = style, #2 = optional space correction, #3 = above, #4 = below
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $#1#3$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip#2}
      $#1#4$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
P \twoarrows[0.4ex]{\Rightarrow}{\nLeftarrow} Q
\]

\[
P \twoarrows[0.5ex]{\,\Rightarrow}{\nLeftarrow\,} Q
\]

\[
P \twoarrows{\rightarrow}{\nleftarrow} Q
\]

\end{document}
```

I provide for a “vertical correction”, because the bounding boxes of the two arrows might get in the way. In the middle display I show a possible correction to the optical effect in the top one.

[image]

Can you realize this in MathJax? I doubt it.

For the last one, it's better to load `old-arrows`: with

```
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}
```

if you input the last display as

```
P \twoarrows{\rightarrow}{\nleftarrow} Q
```

you get

[image]